# Do Haskell's `Distribution.SimpleSetup` `buildProgramPaths` and `buildProgramArgs` do anything?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have tried adding a build hook to my `Setup.hs` like so:

```
ourBuildHook :: PackageDescription -> LocalBuildInfo -> UserHooks -> BuildFlags -> IO ()
ourBuildHook =
    let
        defaultBuildHook = buildHook simpleUserHooks

        doBuild descr info hooks flags =
            let
                originalPaths = buildProgramPaths flags
                originalArgs = buildProgramArgs flags
                modifiedFlags = flags {
                        buildProgramPaths = originalPaths ++ [("yo", "dawg")],
                        buildProgramArgs = originalArgs ++ [("what", ["up"])],
                        buildVerbosity = flag verbose
                    }
            in do
                defaultBuildHook descr info hooks modifiedFlags
    in
        doBuild

main = defaultMainWithHooks simpleUserHooks { buildHook = ourBuildHook }
```

Then I run `cabal build`.

But I don't see any effect from my additions to `buildProgramPaths` and `buildProgramArgs` (`buildVerbosity` comes through OK). Are these fields in fact used by `defaultMainWithHooks`, or are they ignored?